# Okhttp3 jar missing okio?

Tags: java, eclipse, okhttp, okio

I am trying to make a simple Java program to upload a bunch of images I have to imgur. But I am running into problem after problem and cannot just get okhttp to work. At this point the time I have spent trying to solve this has been way longer than it will take for me to write the program itself. I am very new to this kind of stuff so be patient with me please.

So, right now I have the following code from [this tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/a-complete-guide-to-okhttp/):

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .addFormDataPart("new", "This is my new TODO")
                .addFormDataPart("image", "attachment.png",
                        RequestBody.create(new File(""), MediaType.parse("image/png"))
                )
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .build();
```

Which is giving an error on the RequestBody.create() part:

```
The type okio.ByteString cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

When Googling this error, I find [this page](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1685) which says I'm missing the okio library. I thought this would be included with the okhttp jar. I download the okio jar anyway and add it to my project, but the error doesn't change. I have no idea what else might be wrong.

Comment: Versions can matter. Which versions of both libraries are you using here?

Comment: 4.9.2 for okhttp and 3.0.0 for okio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured out your problem.

`Okio` source code from `3.0.0-Alpha-10` and above has been re-written with `Kotlin`.

Your code is requiring ByteString.class, for this you need a Java .class.

Use this version https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okio/okio/3.0.0-alpha.9/  This one is written in Java, before the migration to Kotlin.

The code below will compile:

```
package example;

import java.io.File;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;


public class OkHttpExample {

    public void example() {
        
        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .addFormDataPart("new", "This is my new TODO")
                .addFormDataPart("image", "attachment.png",
                        RequestBody.create(new File(""), MediaType.parse("image/png"))
                )
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .build();
    }
    
}
```

See build path dependencies:

[image]

Once in your build path, in eclipse you can open the jar file, and see the contents:  ByteString.class is included:

[image]

Comment: I am using Eclipse, I have both libraries in the /lib folder and both of them on my classpath. You say I need to get both the classpath and IDE to point to the libraries but I am unsure what getting the IDE to point to the library means. I am using okhttp3 4.9.2 and okio 3.0.0 if this helps.

Comment: @parakeet Are you running from inside Eclipse? Or from the Command Line?

Comment: From inside Eclipse

Comment: see edit @parakeet  Okio from version 3.0.0-Alpha-10 has been refactored to use kotlin instead of Java.  You will need to use a version earlier, Alpha-9 to be able to work with it.

Comment: THANK YOU! It didn't work at first and I was getting kotlin errors so I tried downgrading okhttp to version 3.14.9 before realizing it was a problem with okio still and not okhttp. Okio version 1.9.0 works for me. I wouldn't have figured this out myself, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @parakeet You learned something new, so that is great :)

Comment: Okio 2 is kotlin already. https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/okio-2-6f6c35149525

Comment: @YuriSchimke  That is true, but not the source code.  The source code was still Java Compatible.   `The update is also Java source-compatible. When you configure your pom.xml or build.gradle to use the new version you won’t have to change any .java code to get a clean build. (Our changelog notes one minor exception to this, unrelated to the Kotlin transition.)

But the update is not Kotlin source-compatible; `

Comment: You only have binaries of okhttp and okio, and your code in a java file.  So I don't understand your answer. "Your code is requiring ByteString.class, for this you need a Java .class."